# Centering buttons programatically in Swift

Tags: swift, button, layout, google-signin, centering

I am trying to center Google Sign In and Sign Out buttons programmatically. In order to put both of them in the third quarter. I create 2 views that I wanted to put buttons to their center, in Storyboard.

```
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
    let gSignIn = GIDSignInButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: loginView.frame.size.width, height: loginView.frame.size.height))
    loginView.addSubview(gSignIn)
    gSignIn.center = loginView.center
    
    
    let gSignOut = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: signOutView.frame.size.width, height: signOutView.frame.size.height))
    gSignOut.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0)
    gSignOut.setTitle("Sign Out", for: .normal)
    gSignOut.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)
    gSignOut.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.signOut(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    gSignOut.center = signOutView.center
    self.signOutView.addSubview(gSignOut)
```

As you can see, also I am trying to resize buttons according to view size which helps me to resize buttons depend on device size.

Here is the second half of my storyboard.

[image]

Here is the simulator screen when I run the code.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain how you defined loginView and signOutView

Comment: Use autolayout instead set rect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use auto-layout instead of setting frame.center, it will be more flexible.

Autolayout goes like below code.

```swift
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()

let gSignIn = GIDSignInButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: loginView.frame.size.width, height: loginView.frame.size.height))
gSignIn.translatesautoresizingmaskintoconstraints = false
loginView.addSubview(gSignIn)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    gSignIn.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: loginView.leftAnchor),
    gSignIn.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: loginView.rightAnchor),
    gSignIn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: loginView.topAnchor),
    gSignIn.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: loginView.bottomAnchor)
])
```